# What are these very wide circles I saw on google map in Madagascar?

Tags: geography, satellite-oddities

I was searching for the baobabs in Madagascar and found these wide circles near Avenue of the Baobabs...What are these?[image]

Here's the coordonates 20°16'53"S 44°28'49"E, and here is a link: https://maps.app.goo.gl/PWqZ6BioBrV1sRbt7

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's called center pivot irrigation. A long irrigation rig sprays water over a small part of a crop field to be irrigated. To cover the entire field, the irrigation rig rotates in a very large circle about a central pivot point. The result is circles such as those shown in the question. This technique is used worldwide for agriculture in semiarid areas where water is somewhat abundant but rain is not abundant (or is infrequent). Those circles are even more impressive in desert-like areas. What one sees is circles of green surrounded by brown.

Comment: See [here](https://maps.app.goo.gl/ubZwSgYiKHqjajsy5) for a clearer example in the US, and [here](https://maps.app.goo.gl/b6YpFLge5SiBP3Hs6) for the desert example in Saudi Arabia.

Comment: I thought too that it was center pivot irrigation, but if that's what they are, they are not irrigated any more. The rig is clearly not there any more in these fields, and the grooves in which the wheels of the rig run are not there any more either. Furthermore, most of the fields now have trees growing in them. I think they *used* to be center pivot irrigated, but that that practice has been abandoned there.